# Finding reaction rate constant for second order equation in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, concentration

I’m working in Mathematica for my master’s project and I can’t work out how to find $k$ in the second order rate equations where I have a concentration vs time graph for $\ce{AHA}:$

$$\mathrm{rate} = k[\ce{AHA}][\ce{H}].$$

I have the starting concentrations for $\ce{AHA}$ and $\ce{H}.$

Comment: What is the integrated form of the second order equation?

Comment: Are the starting concentrations [AHA] and [H] different or same? This information is important to determine which integrated rate equation to use.

Comment: @Ele If you are using Mathematica a lot, you may find [Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com) useful.

Comment: If your question is about Mathmatica, you should  show us the math you want to work out in Mathematica. If you don't know what the mathematical description of your problem is, you should show us the data and tell us where you got stuck.

Answer (score 4):

The general second order equation is

$$\frac{\mathrm d[A]}{\mathrm dt}=-k[\ce{A}][\ce{B}]\tag{1}$$

with $[\ce{A}]_0,$ $[\ce{B}]_0$ the initial amounts. At a time $t$ there are $[\ce{A}]_0-x$, and $[\ce{B}]_0-x$ remaining if amount $x$ reacts. Thus

$$\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}=k([\ce{A}]_0-x)([\ce{B}]_0-x).\tag{2}$$

You should be able to integrate this from $0\to x$ by using partial fractions or directly using computer algebra. The result is

$$\ln\left(\frac{[\ce{A}]_0-x}{[\ce{B}]_0-x}\right)=k([\ce{A}]_0-[\ce{B}]_0)t+\ln\left(\frac{[\ce{A}]_0}{[\ce{B}]_0}\right),\tag{3}$$

so that you can plot (as Maurice has pointed out) the left hand side vs $t$ and obtain the rate constant $k$ from the slope $k([\ce{A}]_0-[\ce{B}]_0)$ in units $\pu{dm^3 mol^-1 s^-1}.$

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way you could get from eqn. (2) to eqn. (3) in porphyrin's answer using Mathematica.  I made extensive use of the Part function, whose shorthand is "[[ ]]", to pull out the desired subexpression from each answer.

E.g., Part[x+y, 1], which means "take the first part of the expression (x+y)", can be expressed as (x+y)[[1]], and returns "x"). But you could, alternately, just do copy and paste.

[I used "y" in place of porphyrin's "x" just because I'm used to x being an independent, rather than dependent, variable.]

```
ans1 = DSolve[{y'[t] == k (Ao - y[t])*(Bo - y[t]), y[0] == 0}, y[t], 
  t]
ans2 = ans1[[1, 1, 2]]
ans3 = Reduce[
  y == ans2 && Ao > 0 && Bo > 0 && t >= 0 && y >= 0 && k > 0, k]
ans4 = ans3[[2, 2, 2, 4]]
ans5 = Reverse@Simplify[MultiplySides[ans4, t]][[1, 1, 1]]
ans6 = ans5 /. {(Ao - y) -> A, (Bo - y) -> B}
ans7 = ans6 /. {A -> "[A(t)]", B -> "[B(t)]"}
```

And here is what it would look like.  You would just need to plot the LHS of ans6 vs. t; a linear regression would give you the slope, which is the rate constant.  Note that "Log" in Mathematica is the natural log (ln), not the base-10 log:

[image]

Comment: If the intent is to fit actual experimental data, a direct nonlinear fit is generally going to be much more accurate than linear regression to a plot of the log unless proper weighting is performed. Generally speaking, linear regression for this application is considered very outdated

Comment: @Andrew  On the contrary, the opposite is true, for both theoretical and practical reasons. THEORETICAL: It's always better to linearize the data if you can because there exist, for linearized data, algorithms that can can always find the global minimum (the true best fit). With non-linear data, you are only certain to find a local minimum; whether you've found the global minimum depends on how clever/lucky you've been in providing starting values for the fitting parameters. PRACTICAL: Experimental data is typically measured data, and is thus typically heteroscedatic rather than homoscedatic.

Comment: ...Specifically, it typically has variability that is proprotional to its magnitude.  To properly build models for such data, it is necessary to minimize the relative, rather than absolute, size of the residuals. Yet none of Mathematica's fitting functions (Fit, LinearModelFit, FindFit NonLinearModelFit) offer such minimizations.  [And I suspect this is true of most other symbolic mathematica systems as well.] Instead, they only offer minimzations based on the absolute size of the residuals (such as least squares), which give poor fits for data in the former category.

Comment: ...And the nice thing is that, when you linearize by taking the logarith of the data and apply least squares, you are minimizing the absolute size of the logs of the residuals, which is equivalent to minimizing the relative size of the residuals themselves, thus achieving an appropriate minimization for heteroscedatic data whose variability is proportional to its magnitude.  [Also: While I put the need, when doing non-linear fits, to specify good starting values under "THEORETICAL", it could go here as well, since it's a pain to find those values; doing a linear fit makes that unnecessary.]

Comment: As your comments demonstrate, data fitting is a large topic, but here are some brief replies: 1) if you can't be sure you have the global min of a nonlinear fit, you need better data 2) linear least squares suffers from disproportional weighting of points farther from the center point 3) without knowledge of the specific measuring system, there's no a priori reason to believe that absolute residuals of logs are any more accurate. The better way to deal with variable error is to include multiple y points for each x and do the nonlinear fit to all of those values simultaneously.

Comment: @Andrew  My replies to your replies: #1 is overly glib; data can be difficult or expensive to obtain, and often we have to work with what we have.  #2:  That disproportional weighting is trivial compared to the disproportionality that typically occurs when you have a large range of measured values (say, when measuring concentrations over a few orders of magnitude). #3: Sure, one can't say anything absolutely a priori.  But when your measured values vary over a significant range (say, a few orders of magnitude or more), it would be an unusual measurement device whose measurement error...

Comment: ....doesn't increase with the magnitude of the value being measured.  You may find these two papers informative:  https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/2017SW001669?scrollTo=references

https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2635088 

Finally, it won't,by itself, address heteroscedacity to  "include multiple y points for each x and do the nonlinear fit to all of those values simultaneously". Rather, after measuring multiple y values, you'd need to determine the variance for each x, and weight the fit according to that variance (more variance -> less weight).

Comment: In addition, there's the issue of model utility.  Typically, if your ind. var. ranges over a few orders of mag., it's far more useful to minimize relative errors rather than absolute errors.  E.g., suppose you want to predict the safe use limit for cables with cross-sectional areas ranging from 1 mm^2  to 1,000 mm^2 (~1 mm dia. to ~ 35 mm dia.).  It would be far more useful to have a model that was optimized to give predictions with min. rel. errors rather than min. absolute errors; in the latter case the predicted errors for the smallest cables could be multiple times the predicted values.

Answer (score 0):

Try to report first the logarithm of the concentration of the reagent versus the time $t$. If it gives perfectly aligned points, going downwards, the kinetics is first order, and the slope of the line is the rate constant $k_1$ in $\pu{s^-1}.$

If the points are not aligned on the logarithmic curve, try to report the inverse $1/c$ of the concentration of the reagent versus time. If the points are aligned, and going upwards, it means that the kinetics is second order. The slope of the line is the rate constant $k_2$ in $\pu{L mol^-1 s^-1}.$

If none of these attempts are satisfied, the kinetics is probably described by a hypothesis of an intermediate state.